# Android GATT BLEScanner support only for Motorola Devices

Tags: java, android, gatt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an application in Android GATT BLE , I can get connection with my target device in Motorola devices only (Tested with Android version 5, 5.0.1,5.0.2) but, other devices like samsung,HTC, Lenovo etc, not working.
I tried to debug the same, I could understand that `mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);` the search is not working.
How can I search and connect with the target by using other than motorola.

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I hope all the other devices you are testing with have Android 4.3 (API Level 18) or above.

Comment: I had Nexus, moto g and samsung S4. 
Initially I also faced problem with samsung s4, but then it got android version update of lolipop, and the problem got solved own its own.

Comment: samsung I have tested versions- 4.4.4, 5.01 and4.4.2